# Use letters a-z in a variable in for loop in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I couldn't find a proper way to express myself fully, because of that I am deeply sorry if I make any mess.

My question is: How can I use letters a..z in a for loop in bash?

```
#Aim is to list commands are the directory /usr/bin
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/bin
for i in {a..z}
array=($(ls --ignore=[!a]*)) #Just lists commands starting with "a"
echo ${array[@]}
```

---

```
#I tried to do a substitution in the below code, where may I be wrong?
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/bin
for i in {a..z}
array=($(ls --ignore=[!$i]*))
echo ${array[@]}
```

Comment: Are you actually running this script with bash, not some other shell? Note that the shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`) *must* be the first line in the file, and that if you run the script with `sh scriptname` it ignores the shebang and uses `sh` instead of `bash`. Also, your examples are missing the `done`, which will cause syntax errors in any shell. And `ls --ignore=[!$i]*` is a really strange and trouble-prone way to get a list of filenames that start with `$i`; just set `shopt -s nullglob`, then use `array=("$i"*)`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Exactly. I don't think this question should be marked as duplicate and this should be the answer :)

Comment: To list commands in */usr/bin* just do `ls /usr/bin`, or `echo /usr/bin/*`.

Answer (score 1):

To loop through *a* to *z* use the following:

```
for x in {a..z}
do
    echo "$x"   # prints alphabet
done
```